# Javascript not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I am trying to resize images without CSS, using window resize. But it's not working on iOS devices. Why is the code running on Chrome developer tools and Android Devices not working on iOS devices?

Note: I have tried CSS media queries but they are not working

```
 function (link) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "ws.asmx/GetServiceDetail",
            data: "{'mainLink':'"+link+"'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: {
                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=1000' 
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (dc, status) {
                var itemImages = dc.itemImages;

                for (var img of itemImages ) {

                    $("#mainSlider").append('<li><img class="img-responsive" src="'+img.ImageLink+'" alt=""></li>');

                    $("#thumbnail").append('<li><img src="' + img.ThumbnailLink + '" alt=""></li>');
                }

                imgSize($(window).width());
```

and

```
function imgSize(gen) {
    console.log(gen);
    $("#mainSlider li img").each(function (i) {
        var img = $(this);
        if (gen<=768) {
            $(img).attr("style", "height: 100%!important; max-height: 270px!important;");
            $(".slider").attr("style", "margin:0 auto;height:310px");
        }
        else {
            $(img).attr("style", "height: 100%!important; max-height: 523px!important;");
            $(".slider").attr("style", "margin: 0 auto!important;height: 583px!important;");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: "*I am trying to resize images without css using window resize.*" Just curious, why in the world is that what you chose to do? Your entire `imgSize` function is easily replaceable with CSS Media Queries.

Comment: You right.Im sorry for the missing expression.Im edit now

Comment: Well, you say that you tried Media Queries and that they didn't work, but you didn't say what kind of problem you had with them. What you are attempting to do is exactly what Media Queries are for. You should look into them again.

Comment: Scott but its not working this code ?